# How to transform a set of time intervals to another set based on a starting set

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, time, intervals

I have a set of time intervals called `setTimes` like so:

```
[a,d] [h,j] [k,l]
```

And another set of times `rawTimes` like so:

```
[a,c] [b,e] [e,g] [f,i] [k,l] [i,m]
```

`rawTimes` needs to be transformed into new intervals that are in the intervals specified by `setTimes`. So the result set is:

```
[a,c] [b,d] [h,i] [k,l] [i,j] [k,l]
```

(where a < b < c ... < m)

Basically the result set should all be contained inside of an interval in the `setTimes` set. It is possible that an interval in `rawTimes` could be split into multiple pieces or that it even never makes it to the final set.

Currently what I did is add each start time in the `setTimes` intervals to a list called `startTimes` and the end time to `endTimes`. So:

```
startTimes = a , h , k
endTimes = d , j , l
```

But I'm stuck there. I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Can you assume set times is in order and not overlapping?

Comment: `setTimes` won't be added in order, but can be sorted. But I cannot assume no overlapping. Same with `rawTimes`

Comment: Can you clarify how `[i,m]` is handled, particularly how a result of `[k,m]` is produced when your `setTimes` contains, at its maximum range, `[k,l]`? (perhaps I'm just misunderstanding the requirements)

Comment: In addition, how do you handle a raw time that spans two set times with invalid intervals in between? Given setTimes `[b,e] [m,p]` how does a raw time of `[c,o]` fit in given it spans `f` through `l` which are not valid?  Do you get two spans: `[c,e]` and `[m,o]` or is it thrown out?

Comment: `[i,m]` becomes `[i,j] and [k,l]`. Sorry the `[k,m]` was a typo. And yes it does split into two spans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this elegantly with [Allen's interval algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allen%27s_interval_algebra)